# Two tables with relation --> insert form --> show multiple attributs but insert Id

Tags: google-app-maker

I have tables with relation and a form to insert new data into one of them. Because of the table has a relation to another table, the form also shows the ID from the other table. But for the user it may be confusing to choose the ID of an entry from the other table because the user does not know whats behind the ID.
So I want to show multiple atributes instead of the ID in the dropdown of the insert form. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: Could you provide some screen, sample code etc for the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

In your dropdown that contains your relation go to the 'names' property and change it from value to binding and make sure to change it to reflect the same binding as your 'options' property, then you need to change it to add parenthesis around the binding and add the javascript map function like so:

```
(@datasources.YourRelatedDataSource.items).map(function(i) { return i.Field1Name + ' - ' + i.Field2Name; })
```

Please see the two screenshots below what this will do:

[image: EditorExample]

[image: PreviewExample]